# Align controls to center in a FlowLayout

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a flowlayout as follows:

[image]

I need to center all the controls on the form (In other words, let's say the form's width is 200. btnOpt1 to btnOpt4 should have their `Left` starting at 100 minus half of the button width, **not 0.**)

Comment: `FLowLayout` is not designed for that.

Comment: @SLaks can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: do you know that what are you trying to implement?? your first point contradicts second point regarding layout.. on which condition you will put them back according to your first condition??... rather than using flowlayout panel, put the control in panel and then use the anchor property or dock property as per your requirment..

Comment: @NiranjanKala Either one or the other was fine with regards to implementation. But I removed the second one just to keep you happy and keep the question relevant.

Comment: This is another of those cases where WPF wins.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it two ways but with some limitation of each one.

1. Using `Anchor` property
2. Using the layout control with help of `Docking` and `Anchor` properties.

**Method 1: Anchor Property**

> Controls are anchored by default to the top left of the form which
>   means when the form size will be changed, their distance from the top
>   left side of the form will remain constant. If you change the control
>   anchor to bottom left, then the control will keep the same distance
>   from the bottom and left sides of the form when the form if resized.
>
> Turning off the anchor in a direction will keep the control centred in
>   that direction when resizing.

Example :

```
public TestForm12()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   Button btn = new Button();
   btn.Width = this.Width - 10;
   btn.Height = 20;
   btn.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - btn.Width) / 2;
   btn.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - btn.Height) / 2;
   btn.Text = "click me";
   this.Controls.Add(btn);
   btn.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;               

}
```

**2. Using the layout control**

1. Add TableLayout Control, Set it’s Dock property to Fill.
2. Add 1 Row with Size Type style Percent 100%
3. Add 3 Columns Column1(Size Type – Percent(100%)), Column2(Size Type – Absolute(200px)),  Column3(Size Type – Percent(100%)).
4. Now Add Panel Control to Column2 and Set it’s Dock property to Fill
5. Add Buttons to this control and set their Size as you want and Set Their Anchor Property to AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top

Example - Designer.cs code snippet of the form.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
 {
     this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
     this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
     this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
     this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
     this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
     this.SuspendLayout();
     // 
     // tableLayoutPanel1
     // 
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 3;
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 200F));
     this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel1, 1, 0);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
      // 
      // panel1
      // 
      this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
      this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
      this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(45, 3);
      this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
      this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 256);
      this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
      // 
      // button1
      // 
      this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 9);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // button2
    // 
    this.button2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 38);
    this.button2.Name = "button2";
    this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 23);
    this.button2.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button2.Text = "button1";
    this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // TestForm11
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
    this.Name = "TestForm11";
    this.Text = "TestForm11";
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

 #endregion

private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

Hope this help..

Comment: For me it was enough to put the AnchorStyle to `None` (no need to set left or anything else), I wonder if I am missing anything.

Comment: if you are using that control in Table layout panel then it may work.. In case 2 it may be correctly work if you set AnchorStype to `None`.

Answer (score 11):

I'd go with [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) instead:

- Put TableLayoutPanel on your form
- Set dock style `Fill` to panel
- Leave only one column inside panel
- Create row for every button (and put buttons to table cells)
- Set row size type `Autosize`
- Set dock style `Fill` to every button, except last one
- Set dock style `Top` to last button

BTW in your solution you should iterate over flowLayoutPanel controls instead of form controls. Also consider subtracting horizontal margin and padding from width:

```
foreach (Control control in flowLayoutPanel.Controls)
{
    control.Size = new Size(flowLayoutPanel.Width - control.Margin.Horizontal,
                            control.Height); 
}
```

But I advise you to use TableLayoutPanel instead.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by changing the margin values. I am adding my content to a panel though.

**C#:**

```
int horizontalMargin = (int)(0.5 * (this.containingPanelOrForm.Width - this.button.Width));
this.btnOptX.Margin = new Padding(horizontalMargin, 0, horizontalMargin, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m not good in C# but you can also add a panel in flowlayoutpanel with the same width of flowlayoutpanel. Then you can add in the Panel created in running time the button you want and set the dock to left or right. As you wish. Let me show a example in VB.net and C# (used online converts)

**VB.net**

```
     Dim btn As New Button
            btn.Text = "Example"
            btn.Name = "Button"
            btn.Size = New Size(60,10)
            Dim panel As New Panel
            panel.Size = New Size(FlowLayoutPanel1.Width, 10) 'size of the flowlayoutpanel + height of button
            btn.Dock = DockStyle.Right
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel)
panel.controls.add(btn)
```

**C#**

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "Example";
btn.Name = "Button";
btn.Size = new Size(60, 10);
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.Size = new Size(FlowLayoutPanel1.Width, 10);
//size of the flowlayoutpanel + height of button
btn.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
panel.controls.@add(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create empty Label with Name = lblEmpty and AutoSize = False. Put this control first in controls list in FlowLayoutPanel1, then add code below.

Example: Assuming three existing labels in FlowLayoutPanel1, the result should be lblEmpty, LabelExisting1, and LabelExisting2, in that order.

```
Dim MarginLabelEmpty As Integer = ((FlowLayoutPanel1.Width - (LabelExisting1.Width + LabelExisting2.Width)) / 2)
        lblEmpty.Width = MarginLabelEmpty
```

I solved my problem by creating this code.

in your case with Button Controls, create **4** new labels with **.Text=""**(**empty**) and put each one at the beginning of each button, **naming labels** as follows: lblEmpty1, lblEmpty2, lblEmpty3, lblEmpty4.

Then Add the following code:

```
Dim MarginLeftbtnOptAll As Integer = ((FlowLayoutPanel1.Width - btnOpt1.Width) / 2)
        lblEmpty1.AutoSize = False
        lblEmpty1.Width = MarginLeftbtnOptAll
        lblEmpty2.AutoSize = False
        lblEmpty2.Width = MarginLeftbtnOptAll
        lblEmpty3.AutoSize = False
        lblEmpty3.Width = MarginLeftbtnOptAll
        lblEmpty4.AutoSize = False
        lblEmpty4.Width = MarginLeftbtnOptAll
```

This center button, increasing the width of the empty label according to the width of the FlowLayoutPanel1

Answer (score 0):

Throwing the buttons directly to the form or a panel (not FlowLayoutPanel), and setting `Anchor = Top` (only Top) for all of them, they won't be centered but will always move proportional to the form's (or container's) sides when resizing.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.SizeChanged

        Dim TotalWidth As Integer = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count * button.Width
        Dim LeftPadding As Integer = (FlowLayoutPanel1.Width - TotalWidth) / 2
        Dim GapPadding As Integer = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count * 5

        If TotalWidth <= FlowLayoutPanel1.Width Then
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Padding = New Padding(LeftPadding - GapPadding, 0, 0, 0)
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use Grid layout instead.